# Java FlatMapFunction in Spark: error: is not abstract and does not override abstract method call(String) in FlatMapFunction

Tags: java, apache-spark

I was trying to run the first [example](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html).

The source code is:

```
/*keyWordCount.java */
            import org.apache.spark.*;
            import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
            import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
            import org.apache.spark.rdd.*;
            import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
            import java.util.*;

            public class keyWordCount {

                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("keyWordCount");
                    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
                    JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("output");
                    JavaRDD<String> dictFile = sc.textFile("keyword");
                    JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                        @Override public Iterable<String> call(String s) { return Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")); }
                    });
                }
            }
```

When I compile using mvn compile package, the following error keep showing up:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] /home/cyberliem/TestSpark/src/main/java/keyWordCount.java:[16,81]
>   error:  is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method call(String) in FlatMapFunction
>
> [ERROR]
>   /home/cyberliem/TestSpark/src/main/java/keyWordCount.java:[17,39]
>   error: call(String) in  cannot implement
>   call(T) in FlatMapFunction
>
> [ERROR] 
>       T extends Object declared in interface FlatMapFunction
>       R extends Object declared in interface FlatMapFunction /home/cyberliem/TestSpark/src/main/java/keyWordCount.java:[17,5]
>   error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

I'm not sure how to fix this, can anyone give me an ideal why it goes wrong?

Comment: try to remove @Override

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
    @Override public Iterator<String> call(String s) { return Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator(); }
});
```

or even simpler using lambdas:

```
JavaRDD<String> words = textFile.flatMap(l -> Arrays.asList(l.split(" ")).iterator());
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and give a feedback later.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification there looks like a version mismatch when using FlatMapFunction on my ellipse and compiling via maven

On ellipse, I had this

```
public Iterable<String> call(String s)
```

On the other hand, when compiling using maven I had to use

```
public Iterator<Rating> call(String s)
```

This caused agony but now it has resolved using latter.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the version of spark is a newer one, we can find that the function call(T t) we should override returns Iterator instead of Iterable,see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html.

As the answer above,what we should do is :

1. import java.util.Iterator;
2. change your code to :

JavaRDD words = textFile.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction() {
    @Override public Iterator call(String s) { return Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")).iterator(); }